# How to create edges

Tags: mesh, scripting, edges

```
import bpy

verts = [["a1",-2,0,0],["a2",-1,0,0],["a3",-1,1,0],["a4",1,1,0],["a5",1,0,0],["a6",2,0,0]]
edges = [["a1","a2"],["a2","a3"],["a3","a4"],["a4","a5"],["a5","a6"]]

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("")
me.from_pydata(verts,edges,[])
me.update()
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("",object_data=me)
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

error is

File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\blender\koch.blend\Text Block", line 7, in 
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 470, in from_pydata
self.vertices.foreach_set("co", tuple(chain.from_iterable(vertices)))
TypeError: couldn't access the py sequence
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

how can I connect verticies in edge array?

I replaced `me.from_pydata(verts,edges,[])`with`me.from_pydata(verts,[],[])`

error is

Error: Array length mismatch (expected 18, got 24)
TypeError: must be real number, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\blender\koch.blend\Text Block", line 9, in 
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 470, in from_pydata
self.vertices.foreach_set("co", tuple(chain.from_iterable(vertices)))
TypeError: couldn't access the py sequence

I understood I can't use string in vertex array.
But in `Text Editor > Templates > Python > Addon Add Object` there is no refference about eges.

Comment: How is "a1" to be interpreted as a vertex coordinate?

Comment: Look at _`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Addon Add Object`_